# Advanced SQL - based on value in table i want to do calculation

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is a situation, for example have a look at below content in the table

```
create table cast_ex(nearly_number varchar2(20));

insert into cast_ex values('10');
insert into cast_ex values('20');
insert into cast_ex values('thirty');
insert into cast_ex values('FORTY');
insert into cast_ex values('Fifty[50])');
insert into cast_ex values('60');

commit;
```

I want to sum all the values where the column nearly_number is completely an integer. In this case I want to sum 10 , 20 , 60. Other rows are not considered since they do not contain only integer values ( ie, they contain characters other than between 0 to 9 )

Desired output:

```
   SUM_INT
----------
        90
```

Comment: Mainly you just need to filter out numeric values.  Lookup using `regexp_like` in the `where` criteria to do that.  Then you can use `sum` to get your desired result.  Let us know if you have any troubles with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `REGEXP_LIKE()` to check if `NEARLY_NUMBER` consists of only digits from the beginning to the end using the `[:digit:]` POSIX class to filter the rows from `CAST_EX` and then use `TO_NUMBER()` and `SUM()`.

```
SELECT SUM(TO_NUMBER(NEARLY_NUMBER))
       FROM CAST_EX
       WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(NEARLY_NUMBER, '^[[:digit:]]+$');
```

Comment: This seems like the most direct answer to the OPs question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to just take those rows which satisfy the integer clause

1) Translate & Replace will remove all things other than integer

2) If what remains is NULL, then original string must be an integer

3) Convert that to number & get SUM.

```
SELECT SUM(TO_NUMBER(nearly_number)) AS SUM_INT
  FROM cast_ex
 WHERE (CASE
         WHEN REPLACE(TRANSLATE(nearly_number, '0123456789', '##########'),
                      '#',
                      '') IS NULL THEN
          'TRUE'
         ELSE
          'FALSE'
       END) = 'TRUE'
```

Answer (score 1):

(Requires Oracle 12.2 or later:)

```
select sum(to_number(nearly_number default 0 on conversion error)) as sum_int
from   cast_ex
where  mod(to_number(nearly_number default 0 on conversion error),1) = 0;
```

or minimising the number of explicit conversions

```
select sum(int_value) as sum_int
from   ( select to_number(nearly_number default 0 on conversion error) as int_value
         from   cast_ex )
where  mod(int_value,1) = 0;
```